# jQuery scroll event only triggered once in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

I'm working on a jQuery hover scroll navigation. I'm using `scrollLeft` and `scrollTop` methods in conjunction with the `.mouseover()` and `.mouseout()`. Everything seems to be working fine expect in Chrome/Safari. I'm noticing unexpected behavior. Mainly that the scroll event only seems to be triggering once. I'm not sure what is causing it or if there is a way to get around this.

Anyway here is my code and a link to the site so you can  see the behavior for yourself. Any help would be great.

URL: http://www.derekhutchinson.com

```
var delay = false;
function Movehorizonal(speed, ammount) {
    var curpos = $('body,html').scrollLeft();
    $("body,html").animate({
        scrollLeft: curpos + ammount
    }, speed);
    delay = setInterval(function() {
        //console.log("tick_horizontal");
        var curpos = $('body,html').scrollLeft();
        $("body,html").animate({
            scrollLeft: curpos + ammount
        }, speed);
    }, speed);
}

$(function() {

    var speed = 400;
    $('#goLeft').mouseover(function() {
        Movehorizonal(speed, -200);
    });
    $('#goLeft').mouseout(function() {
        $("body,html").stop();
        clearInterval(delay);
        delay = false;
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like Google Chrome and other browsers both have the scroll values in different elements..  `$('body').scrollLeft();` seems to only work in webkit browsers, while `$('html').scrollLeft();` doesn't

So, replace

```
var curpos = $('body,html').scrollLeft();
```

With

```
var curpos = Math.max($('body').scrollLeft(), $('html').scrollLeft());
```

and

```
var curpos = $('body,html').scrollTop();
```

with

```
var curpos = Math.max($('body').scrollTop(), $('html').scrollTop());
```

And it works as expected

Js:

```
function Movehorizonal(speed, ammount) {
    var curpos = Math.max($('body').scrollLeft(), $('html').scrollLeft());
    $("body,html").animate({
        scrollLeft: curpos + ammount
    }, speed);
    delay = setInterval(function() {
        //console.log("tick_horizontal");
        var curpos = Math.max($('body').scrollLeft(), $('html').scrollLeft());
        $("body,html").animate({
            scrollLeft: curpos + ammount
        }, speed);
    }, speed);
}

function Movevertical(speed, ammount) {
    var curpos = Math.max($('body').scrollTop(), $('html').scrollTop());
    $("body,html").animate({
        scrollTop: curpos + ammount
    }, speed);
    delay = setInterval(function() {
        //console.log("tick_vertical");
        var curpos = Math.max($('body').scrollTop(), $('html').scrollTop());
        $("body,html").animate({
            scrollTop: curpos + ammount
        }, speed);
    }, speed);
}
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pnSLD/1/show/) | [Source](http://jsfiddle.net/pnSLD/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your events from mouseover/mouseout to mouseenter/mouseleave.

Also, your 'delay' variable, is that declared somewhere with broader scope?

Lastly, 'amount' is spelt with one 'm'.

Comment: delay is declaired outside the scope of both functions because I didn't want to have to pass it around so I just globalized it. I tried changing to mouseenter/mouseleave. The same behavior as mouseover/mouseout. 

I did a little more testing and found out that the EVENT is actually triggering fine in chrome. I can see the console.log appearing over and over in Chrome so I don't think it's the event anymore. This leaves only one other thing and that is the scrollLeft() and scrollRight() methods. Is there some issue with calling this method repeatedly in Chrome?